# GoogleMaps API working in html file but not in JS file

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am working with the example that I have found on the google documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#asynch

I have juste copy/pasted the hello world code and it's working fine: it display me a map at the specified location. But now I would like to be able to work in this map in a JS file to a much readable work, so I just added `<script src="RunUTrail.js"></script>` just before the `</body>`.
This file contains the exact same method found in the `<script>`:

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: -34.397,lng: 150.644},
  zoom: 8
  });
```

So it should do nothing but I have the `ReferenceError: google is not defined`. What am I missing to use the API insinde a JS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your js code for map display in a callback function like initMap() and add the name of the callback function in google maps script source.

HTML Code:

```
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
      <script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

JS Code:

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

Comment: AH ok, missed the part with the callBack. Thanks!